# Get current directory in find command and use in sed - one-liner

Tags: sed, find

I'm using this to find files of a particular name in subdirectories, then editing some content:

```
find prod -type f -name "file.txt" -exec sed -i '' -e "s,^varname.*$, varname = \"$value\"," {} +
```

How can I get the name of the current directory (not the directory the script is executed in, rather the directory the file is found in) and insert it into the replace text? Something like:

```
find prod -type f -name "file.txt" -exec sed -i '' -e "s,^ varname.*$, varname = \"$value/$dirname\"," {} +
```

I'm hoping to keep it as a one-liner. My most recent attempt was this, but the replacement didn't work and I feel there must be a simpler syntax:

```
find prod -type f -name "file.txt" -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    dirname=${file%/*}
  done' sed -i '' -e "s,^varname.*$, varname = \"$value/$dirname\"," {} +
```

Example:

```
value=bar
```

file.txt input:

```
varname = “foo”
```

file.txt output:

```
varname = “bar/directory_name”
```

Comment: Just a general remark, one-liners are not the holy grail.

Comment: Perhaps not the holy grail, but what I want in this particular script

Comment: Specifically asking for a one-liner tells us you'll select the briefest answer instead of the most robust, portable, efficient, easiest to maintain, etc. so it discourages people from bothering to provide good answers which might at least partially explain why you only have 1 answer after 12 hours. Not providing concise sample input/output we could test against doesn't help either.

Comment: Example input and output added.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with GNU awk in the same way:

The sed command you make use of can be replaced with:

```
$ awk --inplace -v v="$value" '(FNR==1){d=FILENAME;sub("/[^/]*$","",d)}/^varname/{$0="varname = "v"/"d}1'
```

So your `find` woud read:

```
$ find prod -type f -name "file.txt" -exec awk --inplace -v v="$value" '(FNR==1){d=FILENAME;sub("/[^/]*$","",d)}/^varname/{$0="varname = "v"/"d}1' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
find prod -type f -name "file.txt" | 
parallel -qa- --link sed -i 's#\(varname=\).*#\1"{2}{1//}"#' {1} ::: $value
```

We supply 2 sources to the parallel command. The first source is the list of files from the `find` command using the parallel option `-a -`. The second source is the variable `$value`, being only a single value it is linked to the first source using the parallel option `--link`. The `sed` command is quoted using the parallel option `-q` and normal regexp rules apply excepting that the values `{2}` and `{1//}` are first interpreted by parallel to represent the second source and the directory of the first source respectively.

N.B. To check the commands to parallel are as you desire, use the `--dryrun` option and check the output before running for real.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -execdir and spawn a shell:

```
find ... -execdir \
  bash -c 'sed -i "" -e "s,^ varname.*$, varname = \"$value/${PWD}\"," "$1"' -- {} +
```

`-execdir` runs `sed` in the parent folder of the file instead of the folder from where you run `find`. This allows to use 
`$PWD`.

---

Further note: I calling bash with two arguments:

```
-exec bash -c '... code ...' -- {}
                             ^^ ^^
```

I'm passing the `--` as a placeholder. When called with `-c`, bash starts to index arguments at `$0` instead of `$1`. (`$0` would normally contain the script's name). That allows to use `$1` for the filename from `{}` which is imo more readable and understandable.